# Extract specific column information from table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have several *.txt files with 3 columns information, here just an example of one file:

```
namecolumn1   namecolumn2     namecolumn3
#----------------------------------------
name1.jpg         someinfo1     name

name2.jpg         someinfo2     name

name3.jpg         someinfo3     name

othername1.bmp    info1         othername

othername2.bmp    info2         othername

othername3.bmp    info3         othername
```

I would like to extract from "namecolumn1" only the names starting with *name* but from column 1.

My code look like this:

```
file1    = fopen('test.txt','rb');

c        = textscan(file1,'%s %s %s','Headerlines',2);

tf       = strcmp(c{3}, 'name');

info     = c{1}{tf};
```

the problem is that when I do disp(info) I got only the first entry from the table: name1.jpg and I would like to have all of them:

```
name1.jpg

name2.jpg

name3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much there. What you're seeing is an example of MATLAB's [Comma Separated List](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true), so MATLAB is returning each value separately.

You can verify this by entering `c{1}{tf}` in the command line after running your script, which returns:

```
>> c{1}{tf}

ans =

name1.jpg


ans =

name2.jpg


ans =

name3.jpg
```

Though sometimes we'd want to [concatenate them](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true#br2js35-12), I think in the case of character arrays it is more difficult to work with than retaining the cell arrays:

```
>> info = [c{1}{tf}]

info =

name1.jpgname2.jpgname3.jpg
```

versus

```
>> info = c{1}(tf)

info = 

    'name1.jpg'
    'name2.jpg'
    'name3.jpg'
```

The former would require you to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the result (and whitespace pad, if the strings are different lengths), whereas you can index the strings in a cell array directly without having to worry about any of that (e.g. `info{1}`).